# Display data from unrelated table (model) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Street` model and a `Map` model. They have nothing to do with each other. I want to use the `Map` model to help with selecting a map for a Leaflet map (maybe the wrong way, but I'm trying to have an opacity slider for a map and the existing overlays assume points or lines).

So I want to display the table (a list of all the available maps) from `maps` on a page in `streets` (`show` and `edit`).

`streets_controller.rb`:

```
class StreetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_street, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # Trying to make list of maps available to streets views for working with the map
  @maps = Map.all

  # GET /streets
  # GET /streets.json
  def index
    @streets = Street.all # Without pagination. Added Listing 10.46
    # @streets = Street.paginate(page: params[:page]) # With pagination
  end

  # GET /streets/1
  # GET /streets/1.json
  def show
    gon.streetExtentArray = @street.extent_array
  end

  # GET /streets/new
  def new
    @street = Street.new
    gon.streetExtentArray = @street.extent_array
  end

  # GET /streets/1/edit
  def edit
    gon.streetExtentArray = @street.extent_array
  end

  # POST /streets
  # POST /streets.json
  def create
    @street = Street.new(street_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @street.save
        format.html { redirect_to @street, notice: 'Street was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @street }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @street.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /streets/1
  # PATCH/PUT /streets/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @street.update(street_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @street, notice: 'Street was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @street }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @street.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /streets/1
  # DELETE /streets/1.json
  def destroy
    @street.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to streets_url, notice: 'Street was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_street
      @street = Street.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def street_params
      params.require(:street).permit(:prevName, :currentName, :dateEarliest, :dateLatest, :where, :extent_json, :extent, :extent_array, :numBlocks, :ref1, :ref2, :ref3, :notes)
    end
end
```

In `streets/show.html.erb`

```
<div class="col-1">
  <% @maps.each do |map| %>
    <p><%= map.name %></p>
  <% end %>      
</div>
```

Where `name` is a field in `Map` model.

`localhost:3000/maps` screenshot
[image]

Error:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass.

This is basic Rails, but obviously beyond my limited knowledge. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Can you post your complete controller? Also (unrelated to current error), it should be `map.name` instead of `@map.name`.

Comment: Changed `streets/show.html.erb` to ``<%= map.name %>` and get same error as you suggested. In fact I had it like this through most testing. But thank you for the comment. Added controller to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not setting `@maps = Map.all` in any action within your controller, so its not available and thus `@maps` is `nil` in your view.

To solve this issue move that line to you `show` action:

```
def show
  @maps = Map.all
  gon.streetExtentArray = @street.extent_array
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I still need think harder about what everything is doing. Works of course. Now to see if I can make it do what I want.

Comment: @Greg Glad to help! Also consider using a `before_action` callback (just as you did with `set_street `) if you plan to access `@maps` from more actions.

Comment: I''ll look at that. I've have to go figure out why it's there. I sort of get  it. Either the generator put it there or the Hartl tutorial which I used to build the foundation of the site. Much to learn. I need a reason to build more sites to get the hang of it. Thank you again for your help.